How to dynamically hide/show entire column groups in Ag-grid community?
I would like to mimic a simple form of the side bar of Ag-grid-enterprise: collect (using JavaScript) all column groups in a grid, and for each of them set a checkbox to show or hide the whole group.
I know I can hide columns with gridApi.setColumnsVisible(['col1','col2'], false), as explained in this question. However, I'd like to hide entire column groups at once. Is there a simple way to do this instead of hiding the columns "by hand"?
If I have to do it per column, is there a simple way to get the columns in a given column group?

you can use the getColumnGroup() or getColumns() method to get columns. then create a list using that result and pass in to the visible function

Thanks! getColumnGroup() is one of the workarounds I was looking for (there's also getProvidedColumnGroup, but I don't get their difference). I have managed to get the columns in a group with gridApi.getColumnGroup('ColGroup').children.map((column) => column.colId) (not sure if this is the best option), then I can use gridApi.setColumnsVisible() on those. If you build an answer on that, I can accept it (as it doesn't seem to be another simpler option).

can u try if this also works setColumnsVisible(gridApi.getColumnGroup('ColGroup').getLeafColumns(), false)

Oh, that works and is even better! Thank you! Please, send an answer with that solution.

you can use the getColumnGroup by passing in the groupId. This will give the group of interest.
function setColumnsVisible(
    keys: (string | Column)[],
    visible: boolean
): void;

setColumnsVisible accepts an array of string or array of Column
Now you can use 2 options. First is to map through the children and create an array of col names and then pass in to the set. This uses the string[] approach.
const cols = gridApi.getColumnGroup('ColGroup').getChildren().map((column) => column.colId)
gridApi.setColumnsVisible(cols, false)

or there is getLeafColumns which gives an array of Column instances. You can use with the Column[] approach
setColumnsVisible(gridApi.getColumnGroup('ColGroup').getLeafColumns(), false)


I now have a follow-up to this question: Is there a way to get a list of all existing column groups? I have found gridApi.getAllDisplayedColumnGroups(), but that does not get hidden groups. There is no gridApi.getAllColumnGroups()...

One option that I found was directly from the column definitions: gridApi.getColumnDefs().map((column) => column.headerName). This way I get either the group of the columns that are not part of groups.

@Filipe havent found a straighforward way. but should be possible as you mentioned

Now that I'm implementing this, I see a big problem with this solution: gridApi.getColumnGroup(groupid) returns null after I set them with gridApi.setColumnsVisible(cols, false). So for hiding it is fine, for showing them again it does not work. edit: found even two closed issues about that: here and here

might have to go with the not so simple way https://plnkr.co/edit/h5McdaVGNnVKY2nk?open=app.component.ts . you can also try to ask as a new question to get more attention to queston

Indeed, I was planning to do something like const gp = def.find((d) => d.groupId === 'Name&Country');. This already saves me some time. Thanks! :)
